# php, mysql best way to access static reference table

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for some ideas. I am writing this PHP app that has a reference table. The data in this reference table is pretty static. I use it to populate select lists for dynamic forms as well as refer to it other places as well.

The table is basically:

```
key = stored in other tables
description = a long description of the key
```

My app is going to be referring to this table alot. the table has about 600 rows.

I am looking for suggestions on how best to to access this info. One page could refer to it
20 times.

I am looking for opinions of what is the fastest and most efficient.

I am leaning towards creating a prepared statement at the beginning of the page and then just pass in the new params each time and let mysql handing the caching.

Would a stored procedure be any faster, or load the table into a session array

thanks for any ideas, suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'd wait to try optimizing that until it becomes a problem.  Realistically, 20 simple key-lookup database queries won't take a noticeable amount of time (unless you have a remote database, in which case you might get a bit of lag from the network traffic)

Comment: If you are accessing one table for one page load, its not advisable do a DB fetch 20 times. You can build a data structure once and access that thereafter. This assumes that the data is going to stay static. Also you could use some caching if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned, if you can get away with just making the calls then you can do that.

If performance is an issue, or you'd feel better making it quicker it sounds like this table is a good candidate for caching since it's using key value pairs and rarely changes.

Look into apc or memcache. An example of this (using apc) would be:

```
function getDescription($key){
    $result = apc_fetch($key);//Possibly prefix with method unique prefix.
    if($result === false) {
        //No result stored
        $result = getDescriptionFromDatabase($key);
        apc_store($key, $result);//Can also add a ttl if needed
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This will only grab the result from the database once (until server/php reset e.t.c.) reducing the database calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for speed, and to be honest, you have to have a significant amount of traffic for this to become a problem in the first place, I would recommend creating procedures to make tables that you can call without adding WHERE parameters (so you would have  5 different tables if you have 5 different select statements on your page).  And since your data is mostly static, you would only have to run the create table procedures through events ever so often.